# How to Convert String of numbers to a distinct ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a troubles with an application.

I would like to move my String into this `ArrayList`.

My String contains numbers like 15 17 18 110 113 (numbers from 1 do 200).
I have about 80 numbers in one String, eg.:

```
I/System.out: 15 13 13 12 12 11 11 21 21 39 39 38 38 40 40 41 41 42 42 43 43 74 74 75 75 76 76 77 77 78 78 80 80 99 99 100 100 102 102 103 103 105 105 104
```

While I have `List<String> tmpPath = new ArrayList<>();` and I have tried two different methods:

1.

```
public void transferStringToArray(string s1){
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
        int extra = 0;
        if(s1.charAt(i) != ' '){
            String x = Character.toString(s1.charAt(i));
            tmpPath.add(extra, x);
        else extra++;
    }
}
```

where the output is:

```
I/System.out: [4, 0, 1, 5, 0, 1, 5, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 8, 0, 8, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 8, 3, 8, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1]
```

(numbers are printed from last to first number which is wrong with my assumptions)

2.

```
public void transferStringToArray(string s1){
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        if(s1.charAt(i) != ' '){
            String x = Character.toString(s1.charAt(i));
            tmpPath.add(x);
}
```

where the output is in good order, but one number means one index of an array.

```
I/System.out: [1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 8, 3, 8, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 0, 8, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 4]
```

Do you have any ideas how to **move full number as one index** separated by a space?

Also I have one more question:
**How could I delete all repeated numbers?** I know, that numbers are printed once or twice but in the result I have to have unique numbers.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is a `split` with space `s.split("\\s+")`, and then put the result in a `Set` like this:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")));
```

Or if you want to maintain the order, you can use :

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")));
```

If you are looking to use List and nothing else, then you can use, `distinct` like so :

```
List<String> set = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+"))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Outputs**

```
[15, 13, 12, 11, 21, 39, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 99, 100, 102, 103, 105, 104]
```

Comment: `Set` interface wouldn't guarantee order. Kindly update your answer to maintain the order. May be a `LinkedHashSet`. Also, the OP is about `List`. not `Set`. so may be convert your `set` back to `List` at the end.

Comment: @SunilDabburi ok, I edit my answer, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, the idea with `LinkedHashSet` is good. Thanks for answering. This is working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sticking with Set, as MaciejB wanted to eliminate duplicates and that's the contract of Set.
And, as MaciejB mentioned order too, I parsed them as Integer & put 'em in a TreeSet.

That looks like this:

```
Set<Integer> set = Stream.of(s.split("\\s+")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Or if you prefer multiple lines:

```
Set<Integer> set = Stream                // Result is ordered, parsed Set
                .of(s.split("\\s+"))     // -> String[]
                .map(Integer::parseInt)  // -> Integer[] for order in TreeSet
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)); // no duplicates
```

Outputs:

```
[11, 12, 13, 15, 21, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 99, 100, 102, 103, 104, 105]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To convert space separated string into an array list :
   You first need to split your string into an string array and then convert it into array list

```
 public void convertStringToList() {
        String stringToSplit = "15 13 13 12";
        String[] splittedString = stringToSplit.split(" "); // Will split string based upon the space into an string array
        List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList(splittedString);
    }
```

2. To remove the duplicates, you can insert all the array lists value into a Set. A set is a data structure in java which stores only unique values.

```
  Set<String> uniqueValuesSet = new HashSet<>(listOfStrings);
  for(String str : uniqueValuesSet) {
      System.out.println(str);
   }
```

3. In 2nd point, you might see your output is in random order. That is because HashSet doesn't maintain order of elements. If you need to maintain order as well. Use LinkedHashSet.

```
       Set<String> uniqueValuesSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(listOfStrings);
        for(String str : uniqueValuesSet) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Note: This solution assumes number in the original string are single space separated. If you want solution irrespective of number of spaces between 2 numbers, replace this line in point 1

```
 String[] splittedString = stringToSplit.split(" ");
```

To

```
String[] splittedString = stringToSplit.split("\\s+");
```